# How to fix cannot find module error when making discord bot?

Tags: discord, bots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Hq1.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nARNn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLkxq.png)

i am new to coding and dont know why this error is popping up when trying to get my bot online. Both images are above

Comment: Hey Alex, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post any relevant code, as well as any errors you are receiving as *text* and not images. This will help Google and Stack better identify your question, and it will make it easier for users with the same question find this with more ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your package.json file run the code `npm init` in your terminal and fill it all out.

If you already have, then it is looking for the line that will say `"main":  "index.js",`

Looks like this (yours will be different so don't copy and paste):

```json
{
  "name": "gh0st",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "StackOverflow testing bot",
  "main": "ghost.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ghost.js"
  },
  "author": "Gh()st",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.3.0",
    "discord-modals": "^1.3.5",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: what do i do to it?

Comment: Can you update your question with your package.json file contents

Comment: If you don't have a package.json file then run the code `npm init` in your terminal

Comment: i just added the file image

Comment: Change `"(main.js)"` to `"main.js"` make sure that if it is not in the same folder as the package.json file that you include the path. `"./bot/main.js"` but if it is in the same folder then it's the first thing I said.

Comment: Just noticed that your error code shows that it is looking for an `index.js` is that a file in the file tree?

Comment: no idea i just started doing this today and just followed a youtube video

Comment: Did you create a file that you named index.js? This is your file tree https://i.postimg.cc/5tMWPLbt/Screenshot-2022-04-15-204649.png

Comment: no i didnt just main.js

Comment: Ok then start you bot and see if your error is gone

Comment: same thing happened